# Proving $||f-S_nf||_2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: continuity, inner-products, approximation, density-function, approximation-theory

I am looking at the inner product space $L_{2 \pi}^2$ of square integrable 2$\pi$-periodic functions on $\Re$, with the inner product defined by: $<f,g>$ = $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)g(x) dx$.

For $f$ $\in$ $L_{2 \pi}^2$, let $S_nf$ be the best $L^2$-approximation to $f$ out of $\prod_n$, where $\prod_n$ is the space of all trigonometric polynomials of degree at most $n$.

Since for every $f$ $\in$ $L_{2 \pi}^2$, $||S_nf||_2 \leq ||f||_2$. (Proven with the use of Bessel's inequality)

How do I prove that for every $f$ $\in$ $L_{2 \pi}^2$, $||f-S_nf||_2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I believe at some point, we can use the concept that $C_{2\pi}$ is dense in ($L_{2 \pi}^2$, $||. ||_2$) where $C_{2\pi}$ is the space of all continuous $2\pi$ periodic functions on $\Re$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you studied Hilbert spaces and orthonormal bases? This is just basic result in the theory of Hilbert spaces and the completeness of the orthonormal  sequence $(e^{inx})$

Comment: Hi @KaviRamaMurthy! I have not come across Hilbert spaces and orthonormal bases! Is there other ways to prove without using those basic results? Cheers

Comment: You can have a look at the book 'Fourier Analysis' by Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi. You can find a proof of this statement in the chapter on 'Proof of mean square convergence' (page  77). (The book should be available freely if you 'google' it)

Comment: Hi @Jake28, I will take a look. Thank you :)